# tabulate showing "\n" while printing

Tags: python, python-3.7, tabulate

I would like to print a table on the terminal and for that I use the [tabulate](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate/src/master/) package but I have extra return chariot '\n'. How can I remove them?

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
df = pd.DataFrame({'schools' : ['Harvard', 'MIT', 'UCal', 'Cornell'],
                   'Faculty' : ['CS', 'Psychology', 'Biology', 'BioInformatics']})
print(tabulate(df,headers='keys',tablefmt='psql'))
```

Result

```
('+----+-----------+----------------+\n'
 '|    | schools   | Faculty        |\n'
 '|----+-----------+----------------|\n'
 '|  0 | Harvard   | CS             |\n'
 '|  1 | MIT       | Psychology     |\n'
 '|  2 | UCal      | Biology        |\n'
 '|  3 | Cornell   | BioInformatics |\n'
 '+----+-----------+----------------+')
```

Comment: When I try your example in my terminal it's fine. How are you using your script?
Is it in a file script.py and then ran with a command like: python3 script.py ?

Comment: Yes I am using a script 'poetry run python file.py'

Comment: Are you using python2?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not actually printing the string, but something else containing the string. In my terminal, if I use your code it works:

```
jvaubien@ml18-pc03 ~/Downloads> python3 test.py
+----+----------------+-----------+
|    | Faculty        | schools   |
|----+----------------+-----------|
|  0 | CS             | Harvard   |
|  1 | Psychology     | MIT       |
|  2 | Biology        | UCal      |
|  3 | BioInformatics | Cornell   |
+----+----------------+-----------+
```

With test.py containing your code sample.

But if I do:

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
df = pd.DataFrame({'schools' : ['Harvard', 'MIT', 'UCal', 'Cornell'],
                   'Faculty' : ['CS', 'Psychology', 'Biology', 'BioInformatics']})
x = tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql')
print((x,))
```

I **get the same result** as you with the parenthesis and the \n.

Are you sure that you print the string and not something else? You have parenthesis around the string which shouldn't be here if you only printed the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no errors.
Probably, it's related to your python version or imported modules.
I've tried your code in my terminal and google-colab notebook both, and get the clean output.

You can try to create new virtual environment and run your code in that new virtual environment.